# Yup / Formik async validation with debounce

Tags: reactjs, formik, yup

How can debounce be applied to the async validation below ([code from Yup's github](https://github.com/jquense/yup#mixedtestname-string-message-string--function-test-function-schema)) ?

```
let asyncJimmySchema = string().test(
  'is-jimmy',
  '${path} is not Jimmy',
  async (value) => (await fetch('/is-jimmy/' + value)).responseText === 'true',
});
```

Answer (score 7):

You can implement it by your self by using `lodash.debounce`:

```js
import { debounce } from "lodash";

// .....

const ASYNC_VALIDATION_TIMEOUT_IN_MS = 1000;

const validationFunction = async (value, resolve) => {
  try {
    const response = await fetch('/is-jimmy/' + value);
    resolve(response.responseText === 'true');
  } catch (error) {
    resolve(false);
  }
};

const validationDebounced = debounce(validationFunction, ASYNC_VALIDATION_TIMEOUT_IN_MS);
```

Then in the validation scheme:

```js
let asyncJimmySchema = string().test(
  'is-jimmy',
  '${path} is not Jimmy',
  value => new Promise(resolve => validationDebounced(value, resolve)),
});
```

Comment: Sounds great, but I could'nt get it working :( resolve function is called with correct value but yup does not seem to retrieve it...

Comment: `validationNameFunction` should be `validationFunction`. it works 

Answer (score 1):

I think this should work. It's copying the solution from [just-debounce-it](https://github.com/angus-c/just/blob/master/packages/function-debounce/index.js) but returning a `Promise` right away, which is what Yup expects.

```
const asyncDebouncer = (fn, wait, callFirst) => {
  var timeout;
  return function() {
    return new Promise(async (resolve) => {
      if (!wait) {
        const result = await fn.apply(this, arguments);
        resolve(result);
      }

      var context = this;
      var args = arguments;
      var callNow = callFirst && !timeout;
      clearTimeout(timeout);
      timeout = setTimeout(async function() {
        timeout = null;
        if (!callNow) {
          const result = await fn.apply(context, args);
          resolve(result);
        }
      }, wait);

      if (callNow) {
        const result = await fn.apply(this, arguments);
        resolve(result);
      }
    });
  };
};

let asyncJimmySchema = string().test(
  'is-jimmy',
  '${path} is not Jimmy',
  asyncDebouncer((value) => (await fetch('/is-jimmy/' + value)).responseText === 'true', 400),
});
```

Comment: Maybe it could work as single field validation, but implementing this into my yup scheme made all validation stop...