# YUP/react-hook-form How create an async validation with debounce and dynamic message

Tags: reactjs, yup, react-hook-form

I read some answers about async validation with debounce:
[Yup / Formik async validation with debounce](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58576825/yup-formik-async-validation-with-debounce)
and dynamic messages:
[How to set dynamic error messages in Yup async validation?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62950190/how-to-set-dynamic-error-messages-in-yup-async-validation)
But I don't find a way to have a dynamic error message inside the debounced function.
I like to set the error message from the API response and avoid sending an API request every time that the user changes the field
Thanks, guys

Answer (score 0):

Well I did face this issue with react-hook-form. Here's what I did:

```
  const debouncedPasswordOnChange = useMemo(() => {
     return debounce((e, onChange) => {
     trigger('password');
     onChange(e);
   }, 800);
  }, []);
```

I declared a debounced callback method using useMemo just to ensure the method reference is preserved across renders. Here's what my JSX looks like:

```
    <Controller
            name="password"
            control={control}
            defaultValue=""              
            render={({ field: { onChange } }) => (                  
                <TextField
                  required
                  fullWidth
                  onChange={(e) => {
                    debouncedPasswordOnChange(e, onChange); // This does the trick.                      
                  }}
                  label="Password"
                  type="password"
                  autoComplete="new-password"
                  error={!!errors.password}
                  helperText={errors.password?.message}                      
                />)}
            rules={{
              validate: async (password: string) => {
               // await ajax call.
              }}/>
```